# Use Headless Chrome to run a flash game and take screenshots

Tags: selenium, flash, screenshot, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

Pretty much what the title says. I don't want to use Selenium since it will be very slow and I will need at least 60 frames per second. Is there other alternatives? Has anyone tried something like this?
I am trying to do this on a game called Winterbells, if that is necessary info at all.
Thanks!

Comment: Even if you run headless chrome creating a video would not be easy yourself. Your best bet would be to find a plugin which can actually create video of a website with flash and see if you then put chrome on headless. You need to first achieve your work in a non-headless one and then work towards a headless one

Comment: **Use Headless Chrome** and **I don't want to use Selenium** don't they sound contradictory? What's the point in tagging #selenium when you `don't want`?